# Mass push notification sending in some intervals

Tags: android, mongodb, algorithm, push-notification, social-networking

I am trying to figure out how Facebook / Twitter sends push notifications like "You have 20 new followers"I don't know how to call it but i want to learn the underlying algorithm of this in Android. Please help, Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android you can execute your code before actually showing a push notification. They could simply send a push notification to all devices with an identifier, then the app can make a request to the server and get the needed information in order to show the push notification.

They can also send one push notification per device, as they can associate the push notification key with the user login, and the server would fire a push notification every time there is an event that demands a push notification.

But there are also other ways of doing this, for example, they can, for example run locally in background and create a local notification when the app decides it is necessary.

Comment: Thank you this really helped !